# laravel link database tables

Tags: php, laravel, database, relationship

I'm making a function to add comments to a post. I can create a comment and save it into the database but I'm struggling with the database relationships.

I have a function `addComment` which saves the comment to the `comment` table which is good. But I don't know how to add the id of the post and the just created comment to my `postscomments` table.

I was thinking of adding something like this to the function:

```
    $post_id = Posts::where('id', $currentPost);

    $postComment = new PostsComments();
    $postComment->post_id = $post_id;
    $postComment->comment_id = $comment->id
    $postComment->save();
```

But I'm pretty sure this isn't the right way to link the tables to each other.

How can I link these tables to each other? and afterwards get the values from the database when they are linked?

my function to add the data to the database:

```
public function addComment(Request $request, String $id)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'comment' => ['required'],
        ]);

        $comment = new Comments();
        $comment->comment = $request->comment;
        $comment->save();

        $response = [
            'id' => $comment->id
        ];

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($response);
        }

        return response()->json($response);
    }
```

my postcomment migration:

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts_comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('post_id');
            $table->integer('comment_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts_comments');
    }
```

my posts migration:

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('description');
        });
    }
```

my comments migration:

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('comment');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

my database model:
[image: database model]

Comment: Can a single comment belong to many posts?

Comment: @IGP no 1 comment can only belong to 1 post. a post can have multiple different comments

Comment: Then your database model is a bit weird. You should have a `users` table, a `posts` table (id, user_id, title, description) and a `comments` table (id, user_id, post_id, body).

Comment: @IGP I have updated my database model like how you said. however I'm still stuggling to how I could link these tables in my laravel function

Comment: After defining Eloquent Relationships in your models, you can use those methods to create related models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in my comment, I think your tables should be

- users (id, ... )
- posts (id, user_id, title, description)
- comments (id, user_id, post_id, body)

```
                               +---------+
                               | users   |
                             1 +---------+ 1
+------------------------------| id (pk) |-------------------------------------+
|                              +---------+                                     |
|                                                                              |
|       +--------------+                                +--------------+       |
|       | posts        |                                | comments     |       |
|       +--------------+ 1                              +--------------+       |
| 0..*  | id (pk)      |---------------+                | id (pk)      |  0..* |
+----->>| user_id (fk) |               |          0..*  | user_id (fk) |<<-----+
        | title        |               +-------------->>| post_id (fk) |
        | description  |                                | comment      |
        +--------------+                                +--------------+
```

As to how you link the tables together, you should declare the foreign key constraints in the migration files.

```php
// posts migration
$table->id();
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
$table->string('title');
$table->string('description'); // consider using text('description') instead if it's going to be large
```

```php
// comments migration
$table->id();
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
$table->foreignId('post_id')->constrained('posts');
$table->string('comment'); // consider using text('comment') instead if it's going to be large
```

[Then you need to define relationships between the models](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships)

```php
// User model
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

```php
// Post model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

```php
// Comment model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

As for how to link your models when adding a comment, you could define a route like this:

```php
Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments', [PostCommentsController::class, 'store'])->name('posts.comments.store');
```

```
class PostCommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request, Post $post)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'comment' => ['required'],
        ]);

        $comment = $post->comments()->create($validated + ['user_id' => Auth::id()]);

        return response()->json(['id' => $comment->id], 201);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining how I'm supposed to do this. If I understand correctly I dont need the 'postscomments' table because the relationship already links the data to the tables?

Comment: You don't need the postcomments table because it's redundant. In `posts`, you know who the author is by adding user_id as a foreign key. In `comments` you know who the author is by adding `user_id` as a foreign key and you know which post it belongs to by adding the `post_id` foreign key.